# Flash/Flex E-Learning framework

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, actionscript

I have started to develop E-Learning application and want to know Are There any frameworks for create interactive courses using flash. I think it should be something like this:

- Should be core engine for read and preview each lesson.
- Each lesson should be described in xml (or something like that) file.
- User (administrator) can add new lesson as xml file with resources (I mean images, video and so on) without changing core engine.

Can you help me to find framework with above functionality or I should create it manualy?
Thanks.

Comment: I don't know of any.  Most frameworks in Flex are for programming problems such MVC or Dependency Injection.  I don't know of any domain specific frameworks.  You might also tag your note w/ ActionScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have decided to write own domain specific framework because I have not found any framework with good functional.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this one: [Open source e-learning platform](http://code.google.com/p/welsy/) for flex 3